# merge multiple large hashes

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to merge 3 hashes using `.merge` method. It works perfectly with small hashes, but when I try whit larger hashes I'm getting an error. Probably a memory overflow.
`[1]    50734 killed     ruby bin/app.rb`

Example:

```rb
a = {sheet_01: { 1=>"One", 2=>"Two", 3=>"Three"} }
b = {sheet_02: { 1=>"aaa", 2=>"bbb", 3=>"ccc"} }
c = {sheet_03: { 1=>"zzz", 2=>"www", 3=>"yyy"} }

a[:sheet_01].merge(b[:sheet_02], c[:sheet_03]) do |_key, v1, v2|
 result << v1 + v2
end

# {1=>"Oneaaazzz", 2=>"Twobbbwww", 3=>"Threecccyyy"}
```

but if I test these hashes with 600 values, my program crash

Comment: _"I'm getting an error"_ – include the error message, please.

Comment: ah. Sorry. I am running a ruby script, no error message is displayed. It only appears:
`[1]    50734 killed     ruby bin/app.rb`

Comment: How do you run your script?

Comment: `ruby bin/app.rb` This script takes values from a spreadsheet in the google spreadsheet. Each sheet has 600 lines. What I'm trying to do is concatenate the [n] line of sheet_01 with the [n] line of sheet_02 and the [n] line of sheet_03

Comment: Do you get any error from Ruby itself? The error you showed is from the shell. Actually, it's not an error at all, it's just an information. It would be interesting to see whether Ruby itself outputs an error and what that error is. Normally, it will for example raise an `NoMemoryError` exception instead of silently dying.

Comment: The hashes you showed, even if all three of them had 600 key-value-pairs, would take up less than 100 KB of memory, so I am curious how you determined that it is memory overflow?

Comment: @EmíliaSantos : You did not mention what platform and hardware you are using, but it is unlikely that you get a memory overflow with such a small amount of data. Maybe you have restricted your memory allowance by defining a terribly small `ulimit`? Do you get a core dump? How does the application behve with 300 data items instead of 600?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I wrote a little benchmark to try and reproduce it, but I failed.

as you can see, I am using a random string of ~1000 characters (an integer of 768 bytes is encoded into roughly 1024 characters), which is 100x the size of your strings. I am using 10000 lines, which is more than 10x what you have. And I am using 26 hashes, which is almost 10x what you have. All in all, my memory usage should be roughly 10000x the one you have.

With this benchmark, the merge itself takes about 1.3s, and the entire memory usage for the Ruby process never even touches 1GB. I also tried it with 100000 lines per sheet, and the memory usage went to a little over 8GB, but still no crash.

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'securerandom'
require 'benchmark/ips'

def generate_sheet
  Array.new(10_000) {|i| [i, SecureRandom.base64(768)] }.to_h
end

def generate_hash
  { sheet: generate_sheet }
end

a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z = 
  Array.new(26) { generate_hash }

Benchmark.ips do |bm|
  bm.config warmup: 20, time: 50
  bm.report do
    a[:sheet].merge(
      b[:sheet], c[:sheet], d[:sheet], e[:sheet], f[:sheet], g[:sheet], 
      h[:sheet], i[:sheet], j[:sheet], k[:sheet], l[:sheet], m[:sheet], 
      n[:sheet], o[:sheet], p[:sheet], q[:sheet], r[:sheet], s[:sheet], 
      b[:sheet], u[:sheet], v[:sheet], w[:sheet], x[:sheet], y[:sheet], 
      z[:sheet]
    ) do |_key, v1, v2| v1 + v2 end
  end
end
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer, made it clear that my problem was in the concatenation of the string. If you do `result << V1 + V2` your program will possibly crack.

Comment: anyway I did `end.values.join('')` and it worked as I wanted

Answer (score 2):

### Avoid Copying Large In-Memory Data Structures Under Memory Pressure

Without a lot more information about your system or your real data, no one can really debug this for you. However, it seems likely that Ruby or its parent process is running out of memory, but the limited error message you provided doesn't tell us that it's being reaped by the OOM killer. It's not a Ruby problem per se; you'll have to look at both your *memory and swap usage* at the system level for that.

However, it's safe to say that merging large hashes the way you are is potentially memory intensive. This isn't just about the size of the hashes, but also (potentially) about their *contents*. If you're under memory pressure, you may want to consider:

1. Using [Hash#merge!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21) rather than [Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge), as the latter will make a new *copy* of the merged hash rather than mutate the existing hashes.
2. Using scope gates to ensure that excess memory from your hash variables are prunable by the garbage collector as soon as you're done with them.
3. Switching to a different storage mechanism, as large in-memory hashes getting passed around is inherently more memory intensive than calls to a database, on-disk structure, or external key/value store.

You may also want to revisit *why* your hashes are so big, and whether that's really the best representation of your data or your business logic. Large, persistent data structures in memory are sometimes an indication that you're not representing or manipulating your data structures as efficiently as possible, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: I agree with everything, except I don't really see the relation to the question. The "large in-memory data structures" the OP is manipulating amount to ~80 KB in total, as a rough guesstimate. I just tried to replicate the OP's problem with a dozen hashes instead of just three, with a thousand lines each instead of just 600, and with 100 character strings instead of 3-5, and it finishes instantly with the memory impact not even measurable.

Comment: @JörgWMittag He obviously didn't include real data, or explain why he thought the error was happening at this section of code. I've seen enough people try to implement a poor man's version of Redis or memcached that I think it's worth calling out the antipatterns, though. That may not be the OP's problem, but I still think it likely.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs @JörgWMittag hey gentle, the problem occurs when I try to concatenate v1 + v2 in result:

`result << v1 + v2`

Thank you for your clarification